# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar una variable global y un Singleton? Java

Tags: java, poo, patrones-de-diseño

Muy buenas mis queridos compañeros, quería preguntaros sobre la diferencia, ventajas y desventajas entre usar una variable global o el patrón singleton.

A continuación dejo un poco de código para que veáis a lo que me refiero.

Entiendo que la variable global al ser estática se podría usar en cualquier parte del programa. pues lo mismo pasaría con el singleton, que ventajas me trae usar un singleton, porque es tan popular?

Singleton:

```
public class Singleton {

    private Singleton() {}
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private int num = 30;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }       
}
```

Variable Global:

```
public final class VariableGlobal {
    private VariableGlobal(){}
    public static int num = 30; 
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Singleton sing = Singleton.getInstance();
        System.out.println(sing.getNum());

        System.out.println(VariableGlobal.num);

    }

}
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias a todos de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

En java no existen variables globales, lo que si existen son variables estáticas.

Un singleton es un patrón de diseño que sirve para limitar a 1 la cantidad de instancias de una clase. Para implementarlo se utilizan variables estáticas, pero no basta con eso ya que también se debe evitar que se puedan crear otras instancias.

Comment: Estas mal quien dice que no hay variables globales en Java para definir  una variable global puede utilizar palabras clave como estáticas, aun que la variable sea estática al final se define como variable global.

Comment: @SoftMolina En que parte de la JLS mencionan variables globales? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3

Comment: Por eso dije para definir una variable como global no que sea tipo global, creo que no hay necesidad de poner la definición de que significa global, al final se entiende por que las variables estáticas son globales.

Comment: @SoftMolina Exacto, no están definidas como tal en la documentación pero se entiende perfectamente que se puede "Emular" su comportamiento, es a lo que me quería referir en la explicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable global puedes alcanzarla en cualquier parte de tu código como tu ejemplo en java, debe ser declarado **public**, el patrón de diseño singleton sirve para generar solo una instancia de un objeto a diferencía de la clase o variable global, esta puede estar dentro de un paquete y no ser visible publicamente, imagina que tienes una clase que genera una conexión a una base de datos, y hay muchos procesos que requieren de esa clase, generarían multiples instancias de conexión a la base de datos, con tu patron singleton evitas abrir tantas instancias de la base de datos o cualquier otro objeto que requieras que sea único.

Comment: Pero en mi ejemplo las dos versiones son publicas y son accesibles desde cualquier parte del código al igual que al definirías protected podrías restringir el acceso a solo packages. Aparte, representa que si tengo la variable global con atributos públicos y nunca le hago un new porque puedo acceder al ser estáticos, estoy manteniendo una instancia, de ahí que sea final, no? y en singletone puedo conseguir lo mismo al tener el método get instance, no se si me explico muy bien

Comment: la palabra reservada ***final*** solo indica que de esa clase no se puede extender o hacer herencia, y efectivamente no existe la "variable global", la forma de darle solución es una clase estática,el problema esta cuando la quieres hacer global, debe ser alcanzable en todas las partes de tu código.

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo, pero mi pregunta iba mas enfocada sobre temas de usabilidad y problemas, por ejemplo, se conoce que una variable global puede interferir en algunos casos y generar problemas ya que ocupa un namespace, en el order de definición, etc. sobretodo experiencias de gente que se ha peleado bastante y alguna vez ha tenido problemas usando uno u otro

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejemplo que has expuesto tal vez no haya mucha diferencia, sin embargo en uno de sus usos más extendidos como lo es una clase encargada de la conexión con una base de datos, el singleton se hace notar bastante, ya que no sirve como una clase de "solo guardar un valor" desde el inicio, si no que contiene métodos para abrir y cerrar una conexión (estamos de acuerdo en que no se quiere tener una conexión abierta "desde el inicio" sin que se necesita realmente), además claro está, de ser la responsable elegir entre crear una conexión en caso de que aún no exista o retornar una conexión ya existente.

En patrones de diseños se utiliza un principio de "Una sola responsabilidad", lo que quiere decir que las clases debería tener solo una responsabilidad, pero como notarás, la clase singleton comunmente tendrá dos: 1) La función por la que creaste la clase 2) Ser la responsable de crear su instancia o retornarla; por lo que algunos consideran que no es un patrón correcto.

Al final del día uno utiliza lo que funciona y aplica patrones comparando el impacto que pueda tener en mantenibilidad vs implementación.